# Update mySQL - Wordpress HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, forms

How can I integrate an HTML form with a PHP script to update a value in mySQL?

How should I place the scripts for them to work together? Any guidelines for best practice?

I am failing to integrate the work. I tried everything I could think of but I am not able to make it work here is a list of what I tried so far:

1. Writing the script in functions.php which caused a fatal error.
2. Creating a new file named index1.php, still not integrating with the HTML form.
3. Putting index1.php in the form action, but still didn't work.
4. Something weird, as shown in the image, but still didn't work.
   [image]

Form:

```
<div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;background-color: #f8f8f8;">
    <form action="index1.php" method="post">
    <fieldset> 
    <div style="padding 10px;text-align:left;"> <textarea name="value" value="12" 
    placeholder="meow" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #f8f8f8"></textarea></div>
<div style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
    <input type="submit" name="ins" value="Update" style="padding: 8px; background-color: #328269">          
</div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP Script:

```
   <?php
if (isset($_POST['ins'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data_array = array(
        'value' => $_POST['value']
    );
    $table_name = 'P100';
    $rowResult  = $wpdb->update($table_name, $data_array);
    if ($rowResult > 0) {
        echo "Data Added Successfully!";
    } else {
        echo 'Error Occurred. Please try again.';
    }
    $wpdb->flush();
}
?>
```

My aim is to embed the form in a popup so that I can allow quick editing of the front end from the Popup when I display all my text in shortcodes retrieved from the database.

Comment: What you do you mean that putting the PHP file in the form action didn't work? That is HTML/PHP 101.

Comment: In form action, I wrote: <form action="index1.php" method="post">, I think I should reference the file location exactly?